# built function sort() - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a sort() function,
nonetheless, I got this message "IndexError: list index out of range"

I know the reason for this message but I am not able to realize the result but without error message.

```py
liste = [10, 4, 9, 6, 11, 8, 1]

i = 0

while i < len(liste):
    if liste[i] > liste[i+1]:
        liste[i], liste[i+1] = liste[i+1], liste[i]
        i = 0
    elif liste[i] < liste[i+1]:
        i += 1

    print(liste)
```

Comment: "I know the reason for this message": then what is preventing you from changing the code to avoid generating this error?

Comment: Its dangerous to use addition in brackets `[]` because once you reach the last member the last member +1 means you are out of range. So be very careful with those fringe cases or accessing list elements.

Comment: Also from my experience a sort manually is done using multiple for loops, and you adjust the inner loop by reducing its number of repeats. A simple google search should help you out. This question is likely a duplicate and will be closed.

Comment: In case the other hints were not enough: `liste` has 8 elements with indexes from 0 to 7. So if `i` is `7` what do you expect to access with `liste[i+1]`?

Comment: Similar to previous comments, you are using `[i+1]`, so your loop should not be allowed to reach `len[i+1]`. You would not run into the error if you changed your first line to `while i < len(liste)-1:`

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop iterating after you check that the 2nd last and the last item are in order. Since you check this by accessing second item at index `i` and last item at index `i + 1`, you want to stop your loop at `len(liste) - 1` instead, to avoid indexing beyond the length of the list, such as:

```
while i < len(liste) - 1:
...
```